# Measure of intersection of a set with its translate

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove that if $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a Lebesgue mensurable set with $\mu(A) \neq 0$ and $\mu(A) < \infty$, then $$\lim_{\| x \| \to 0} \mu(A \cap (A+x)) = \mu(A).$$
I think I can prove this for parallelepipeds, but I'm unable to make it for other sets. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Since you can do it for parallelepipeds maybe you can try the following: consider $U$ open such that $\mu(U\setminus A) < \epsilon$ and prove the result for $U$ (this should be easy since you can write as the union of parallelepipeds).

Comment: I wrote $\mu(A \cap (A+x)) + \mu(U \setminus A \cap (A+x)) + \mu(U \cap (U \setminus A + x)) = \mu(U \cap (U+x))$. Then because $\mu(U \setminus A) \leq \varepsilon$, we have that $\mu(A \cap (A+x)) \geq \mu(U \cap (U+x)) - 2\varepsilon \geq \mu(U) - 3\varepsilon \geq \mu(A) - 3\varepsilon$. This gives what we want, since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary. Is it right? If it is, I only don't know how to prove the result for an open set $U$.

Comment: I can prove that if the result holds for two sets, then hold for the union. The problem I'm getting is how to prove for countable unions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First consider the case of an open set $U$.

Because $U$ is open, for all $t\in U$, $\lim\limits_{\|x\|\to 0}1_{U+x}(t)=1_U(t)=1$.  It follows that $$\lim\limits_{\|x\|\to 0}1_U(t)1_{U+x}(t)=1_U(t)$$ for all $t\in\mathbb R^d$. By the dominated convergence theorem<sup>1</sup>, $$\lim\limits_{\|x\|\to 0}\int_{\mathbb R^d}1_U(t)1_{U+x}(t)\,d\mu(t)=\int_{\mathbb R^d}1_U(t)\,d\mu(t).$$ In other words, 
$$\lim\limits_{\|x\|\to 0}\mu(U\cap(U+x))=\mu(U).$$

---

To reduce the general case to this, Let $\varepsilon>0$ and let $U$ be an open set such that $\mu(U\setminus A)<\varepsilon$.  For all $x$, $$[U\cap(U+x)]\setminus[A\cap(A+x)]= [(U\setminus A)\cap(U+x)]\cup[U\cap((U+x)\setminus(A+x)],$$ so $\mu([U\cap(U+x)]\setminus[A\cap(A+x)])<2\varepsilon$.  It follows that if $\mu((U\cap(U+x))>\mu(U)-\varepsilon$ for sufficiently small $\|x\|$, then $\mu((A\cap(A+x))>\mu(A)-3\varepsilon$ for sufficiently small $\|x\|$. Hence it suffices to show that the result is true for the open set $U$, as done above.

---

<sup>1</sup> In case the use of dominated convergence for a continuous family of functions rather than a sequence as usual seems troubling, note that we can apply it with an arbitrary sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb R^d$ converging to $0$, and having the equality hold for all such sequences is equivalent to equality for the continuous limit.